# Enabling 3D Touch preview for TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, wkwebview, 3dtouch

I've got `TableViewController` that segues to `UIViewController` where `WKWebView` is located. Every TableView cell points to particular local html file, which is then loaded in WebView.

> I can simply check the **`Peek & Pop`** - `Preview & Commit Segues` in Attributes Inspector for that segue, but **the preview will show always the same html file**, rather than different one for each table cell selected.

What is the proper way to implement 3D Touch, or how to somehow prepare the html content for preview in the first `TableViewController`?

---

**[.xcodeproj](https://github.com/pancoq/core)** on my github. More info on demand.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no selected cells when peeking, therefore you cannot just ask the table about the selected cell. Instead, you have to handle the `sender` parameter, which is the `UITableViewCell`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "transporter" {
        guard
            let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
            let path = table.indexPath(for: cell)
        else {
            return
        }

        let selected = filtering() ? filter[path.section].rows[path.row] : list[path.section].rows[path.row]
        let controller = (segue.destination as! Detail)
        controller.result = selected
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afk now, will try this in half an hour, thanks! :)

Comment: bounty available in 20 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i saw your code and you aren't implement 3D touch, first of all you need to check if the 3DTouch is available in your `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
if( UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available{
registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)
}
```

and then, implement the delegate of Preview  UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate, you are talking about pop a viewcontroller with 3dtouch, implement this function in delegate

```
extension:YourViewController:UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate{

   func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
       //Here's where you commit (pop)
       //You are trying to show into tableview, the next code makes this
       //For TableView
      guard let indexPath = tableView?.indexPathForItem(at:location) else { 
      return nil }
      guard  let cell2 = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return nil }
      guard let popVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popVC") as? YourClassViewControllerToShow else { return nil }
     let html = htmls[indexPath.row]
     popVC.html = html
     show(popVC, sender: self)

   } 
}
```

and i switch the code from Detail.swift `viewDidLoads()` to `viewWillAppear()`

```
content.uiDelegate = self
  content.navigationDelegate = self
  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: result?.id, withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "Library")!
  let request = URLRequest(url: url)
  content.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
  content.load(request)
```

with this last, you are insuring the webview always refresh when appear.

Comment: thanks :) if this is working on your side, can you please make a pull request to my GitHub, maybe? because I am missing something..

Comment: Sorry dude, i didnt have Xcode 10, but you can try changing in Library.swift the changes about  UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate, and in the Detail.swift the changes about viewdidload - viewwillappear webView!

Comment: I understand your answer, but gave me a lot of different errors, assuming I did it as expected. I've put first code in firstViewController's viewDidLoad(); second in extensions.swift and third in detail.swift's viewWillAppear...

Comment: the extension is in the library.swift  extension Library: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate{ . //inside function previewcontext }, put on the button ending the class